# Loop trouble while displaying text in TextField

Tags: java, swing, loops, netbeans

I have a small issue with my loop and I can not figure out why it wont work. I am trying to get the TextField to change from one message to the other depending on whether they pressed the button on an Odd try or Even try.

It seems that my `display = count % 2` is somehow messed up and is simply not doing the math correctly. In the console i placed a print statement to test it and it seems to just be printing out `"1"` so it is never odd i guess so it wont print out the other statement?

I am sure this is very simple but I have not been able to figure it out. Thank you for any help!

I will attach a screenshot of the Java source code.

---

JAVA SOURCE CODE:

```
    private void btnClickMeMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    setDisplay();
}                                        

private void setDisplay() {
    int display;

    for(int count = 1; count < 10; count++){
        display = count%2;

        if(display == 0) {
        lblHello.setText(hello);
        } else {
            lblHello.setText(null);
            System.out.println(display);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not always odd. You only have for it to print out display when it is 1 not when it is a 0. Your code works just fine. Maybe add the same print statement in the initial section of the if clause as well if you want that output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is doing math just fine, it's your logic that's messed up. The code is only going to print "1" since you are printing only from the else portion of your if/else block. If you also add a println within the if portion of the block, you'll see plenty of "0"'s printing out.

Your biggest mistake is to use a for loop -- don't do this, since every time `setDisplay()` is called your loop will run and will always end at 9, and only `" "` will be displayed.  Instead get rid of the for loop and increment a counter variable inside the actionPerformed and do your action based on its value.

In the future, don't post code as an image. Post it as text formatted as code so that we can copy and paste it if need be.

Other issues -- don't add a MouseListener to a JButton. Use an ActionListener instead for many reasons, notably so that it behaves like most all other buttons and will activate on space bar press and will deactivate if the button is disabled.

Comment: I aplogize I will fix my screenshot to plain text and thank you for the help! I will accept it after 10min!

Comment: How would i rewrite my code? I am having issues thinking it through while taking out my loop. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashton: again **you don't *use* a loop**. You're thinking linear console programming techniques and that's not what you're creating here. You're creating an event-driven program, and so instead of a loop, you simply increment your counter variable in your button's ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

Put a System.out.println(display); in the if statement. You're only debugging in the else. It's most likely working.